# Generate combinations with condition of minimum hit and percentages in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Example:

[image]

Supposing that based on your criteria you choose 27 numbers from a total pool of 49 to 6/49 lottery, like in the picture above. Next, you input that when you hit at least 6 numbers from all those 27 you already selected then you want to have at least one single ticket with at least 3 numbers.

I am trying to do this using Python. Here is my work:

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_combos(n, k, t):
    nums = [x for x in range(1, n+1)]
    combos = []
    for cmb in combinations(nums, k):
        combos.append(cmb)

    final_combos = []
    for filter_cmb in combinations(nums, t):
        for each in combos:
            if len(sorted(list(set(each).intersection(filter_cmb))))==len(filter_cmb):
                final_combos.append(each)
                break
    return sorted(list(set(final_combos)))


v = 4
k = 3
t = 2
for each in get_combos(v, k, t):
    print(each)
```

**n is the total pool of combinations; k is the combination size; t is the minimum to hit;**

And it seems it is working very well for these input parameters of 4;3;2; as the output is:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
```

But if I change them to 5;3;2; the output is:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 2, 5)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 4, 5)
```

which is wrong because the desired output in this case should be:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 4, 5
2, 3, 4
2, 3, 5
```

Obviously the Python algorithm above is wrong. But how this is accomplished programmatically? What the algorithm above is missing? Also, the examples above are for 100% percentages but how to do it when percentage is smaller?

Thank you!

Comment: Please, explain a little better how the lottery system is working.

Comment: This seems more like a math problem than a programming problem.

Comment: @Yoyoyo can you please tell us what you are trying to do, rather than what you are doing? It seems to be a drawing simulator with fixed conditions from what I gather. And you are just calculating alllll the combinations and then picking among them.

Comment: @scr I am trying to create an algorithm for reducing the number of possible lottery combinations like it is described here: https://www.expertlotto.com/en/help/index.htm and also the same thing here but except that here is without percentage option: https://lotterywheels.io

Comment: @chepner I am trying to generate best possible combinations by filtering them and not to solve some math formulas.

Comment: @LoukasPap It is just an usual lottery e.g. 6/49 or any. You think of choosing some numbers that you think they have bigger chance to be drawn but instead of choosing just 6 and put them on a ticket you choose 27, for example. But not put all those on a ticket because it will be very expensive so you want to generate some best tickets to play by using just these chosen 27 numbers. So you input parameters like described above to hit at least some of the numbers. Please check also the links I posted above to see what I am talking about. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only select 27 of the 49 numbers, you cannot achieve a 95% probability of matching at least one subset of 3 in the 6/49 draw.  there will be multiple combinations of 6 numbers that contain none of the selected 27.   What you can aim for is optimization to minimize the number of combinations that will achieve 95% coverage of the subsets of 3 within the selected 27 given a draw composed only of these 27 numbers.

The actual probability for a draw out of 49 numbers is much less but it could be computed if you provide the function with an extra parameter.

`p = 1-(1-s*c/t)**6`

`s` is the number of combinations of 3 in 27  `27!/3!24!`.

`c` is the coverage of your combinations.

`t` is the total number of combinations of 3 in 49 `49!/3!46!`.

With a selection of 27 out of 49 and 90% coverage `p` is 60%

Here is a function that generates combinations that minimize duplicate coverage of subsets (so fewer combinations are needed) up to a specified probability percentage:

```
from math import factorial
from itertools import combinations

def comb(n,k): return factorial(n)//factorial(k)//factorial(n-k)

def optimalCombos(poolSize,drawSize=6,minSet=3,minChance=100):
    seenSets     = set()
    minSetCount  = comb(poolSize,minSet)
    drawCover    = comb(drawSize,minSet)
    combos       = set()
    
    def genCombo(start=0,prefix=tuple(),maxDups=0):
        if len(prefix)==drawSize:
            return prefix
            return
        for i in range(start,poolSize):
            combo     = prefix + (i,)
            seenCount = 0
            if len(combo) >= minSet:
                seenCount = len(seenSets.intersection(combinations(combo,minSet)))
                if seenCount > maxDups:
                    continue
            combo = genCombo(i+1,combo,maxDups-seenCount)
            if combo: return combo
        
    prob = 0
    dupsAllowed = 0
    while prob*100 < minChance:
        combo = genCombo(maxDups=dupsAllowed)
        if not combo:
            dupsAllowed += 1
            continue
        combos.add(combo)
        seenSets.update(combinations(combo,minSet))
        prob = 1-(1-len(seenSets)/minSetCount)**drawCover
    return sorted(combos)
```

*Note: the function returns combinations expressed as lists of indexes that you can later map to your selected numbers*

output:

```
for combo in optimalCombos(5,3,2):
    print(combo)
    
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 3, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4)
```

Larger pools of number take longer to process but still in reasonable time:

```
# 90% chance of matching a subset of 3 
# in combinations of 6 out of 27 selected numbers.

for combo in optimalCombos(27,6,3,90): 
    print(combo)

(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
(0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9)
(0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13)
(0, 1, 14, 15, 16, 17)
(0, 1, 18, 19, 20, 21)
(0, 1, 22, 23, 24, 25)
(0, 2, 6, 10, 14, 18)
(0, 2, 7, 11, 15, 19)
(0, 2, 8, 12, 16, 20)
(0, 2, 9, 13, 17, 21)
(0, 3, 6, 11, 16, 21)
(0, 3, 7, 10, 17, 20)
(0, 3, 8, 13, 14, 19)
(0, 3, 9, 12, 15, 18)
(0, 4, 6, 12, 17, 19)
(0, 4, 7, 13, 16, 18)
```

If each participation (combination) costs 1$ and the reward for a 3 number combo is 10$, With these these 16 combinations (16$), you should expect to win 10$ * 60% = 6$, so a loss of 10$ on average.

Comment: If you input 5;3;2; on this site: https://lotterywheels.io  the result is different. I know that your algorithm generates combos starting from zero, which is very good because it can be easier to convert them to combos with given numbers and use them as indexes for that numbers list but even so that website (if adding +1 to the generated combos) generates different combos. I know it doesn't use percentages. So, which one is right? I don't have full version of the software to give a try just this website. Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: I gave it a quick look and it seems that their algorithm does something that mine doesn't which is to minimize the number of duplicates *per subset* in addition to minimizing the total number of duplicates (which mine also does).  This explains why my function produces the (3-4) pair 3 times where theirs doesn't.  Both solutions cover all 10 pairs in 4 combinations

Comment: But the results are different. Is this right? How is that two algorithms are right but they are producing different results? Maybe I don't understand exactly, please explain. Which one is better and why are they producing different results? Thank you in advance!

Comment: These algorithms produce combinations that aim to cover all the possible subsets.  There are several patterns of combinations that will accomplish that with the same number of combinations.   For example, if my loops were processing numbers in descending order, a different but nonetheless valid list of combinations would be produced.  In other words there are multiple valid solutions for these combinations.

Comment: You can get the number of subsets covered by a list of combinations using this: `len(set(ss for combo in comboList for ss in combinations(combo,2)))`.  All solutions should give the same value for 100% coverage (e.g. 10 for 5;3;2)

Comment: `from math import comb` instead of using the definition with the factorial

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7 (so no math.comb) but indeed, for later versions don't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @AlainT. Please write a Python version of their algorithm they are using too, please. I wish to have both versions (your one and their, please). Thank you a lot for you help!